# Street view is showing error message in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, kotlin, google-street-view

Hi Am working on google maps. i have added location in a fragment now am trying to add StreetViewPanoramaView to the fragment .  But am getting Oops! something went wrong error message as shown in 2nd image 
this is my code

maps_activity.xml

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_streetview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Open StreetView"
    />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

<com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/streetview"/>
```

This is my MapActivity.kt

```
 button_streetview.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {


     var mStreetViewPanoramaView : StreetViewPanoramaView = findViewById(R.id.streetview)
        mStreetViewPanoramaView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        var streetViewPanorama: StreetViewPanoramaOptions = StreetViewPanoramaOptions()
        streetViewPanorama.panningGesturesEnabled(false)
        streetViewPanorama.position(address)
        streetViewPanorama.userNavigationEnabled(false)
        streetViewPanorama.zoomGesturesEnabled(true)

        var streetViewPanoramaCamera : StreetViewPanoramaCamera = StreetViewPanoramaCamera(25F,30F,1F)
        streetViewPanorama.panoramaCamera(streetViewPanoramaCamera)
        mStreetViewPanoramaView = StreetViewPanoramaView(this,streetViewPanorama)
        mStreetViewPanoramaView.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this)
    })
```

i can successfully retrive latitude and longitude of a place by address and display it in infoWindow and add custom marker as shown in image.
But when i click openstreetview button error message is coming.[image]

This is the StreetView
[image]

This is the logcat
[image]

As This Error message is showing Wrong API key but i have added correct Key as i can retrive and display a marker successfully. Can anyone please tell me where am doing wrong

Comment: Have you enabled billing on your project? (If not you need to do so) Is your API key restricted? (if it is, try unrestricting it for troubleshooting purposes; do you still get the same error message when using an unrestricted API key?).

Comment: Api key is not restricted but I could not add billing account . tried so many time but getting error message .Error. Your card doesn't support automatic recurring payments.

Comment: I see, let me give you a full answer on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting the error described [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#debit):

> If you receive an error such as *Your card does not support automatic
>   recurring payments* or *General decline of the card*, please **select a
>   different form of payment**.
>
> You might encounter these errors if you are using a debit card that
>   requires two-factor authentication to complete an online transaction.
>
> Two-factor authentication requires you to be in-session at the time of
>   the transaction. Cards that require you to be in-session are not
>   usable for subscriptions or similar recurring automatic transactions.

Your street view map should work without problem once you enable billing on your project. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank youi used debit card. Now i will try with another form.